# $H^1$-conforming approximation for elliptic PDE with discontinuous coefficient?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, finite-element-method, elliptic-equations

everyone

Suppose I want to solve the diffusion equation $$-\nabla\cdot a \nabla u=f, \\u=0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega,$$ $f \in L^2(\Omega)$, $\partial \Omega$ is smooth.

I use the standard node-based linear elements on a tetrahedral mesh.

I know that to find some $u \in H^2(\Omega)$, I need to make assumption on $a$: $a(x) \in C^1(\Omega)$ (Evans) or $a(x) \in C^0(\bar{\Omega})$ (another textbook). In this case I can safely build approximation in $H^1_0(\Omega)$.

But I also know that I can define $a$ to be merely piece-wise constant in my code without any harm, and I have seen a lot of such computations.

The question: to which space $u$ belong to in the case of the piece-wise constant coefficient? I would be grateful for a reference.

Comment: I might be wrong but it is likely that you should consider using a mixed FEM where one introduces an independent variable for the flux $a \nabla u$. Then  having a piece wise constant $a$ posesno problem as you approximate the flux in $H(div)$ and $u$ in $L_2$

Answer (score 1):

It is quite standard to have $a$ piecewise constant, or more generally a piecewise constant diffusion matrix. Here we consider $a:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, but shall require additional regularity.

In the stated problem, you have already assumed that the gradient exists. So your question actually boils down to whether or not a solution to the variational problem exists: find $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ such that
$$\langle a\nabla u,\nabla v\rangle_{\Omega} = \langle f,v \rangle_{\Omega}\quad\forall\,v\in H^1_0(\Omega).$$
If a solution to the above exists, then it follows that it is in $H^1_0(\Omega)$. We require to make the assumption that there exist real numbers $\underline{a},\overline{a}>0$ such that
$$ \underline{a} \le a(x) \le \overline{a}\quad\forall\,x\in\Omega.$$
Under this assumption the norm $|v|_{a,H^1_0(\Omega)}^2:=\langle a\nabla v,\nabla v\rangle_{\Omega}$ is well defined and equivalent to the $H^1_0$ norm, thus existence and uniqueness follows from the Riesz Representation Theorem.

Note that the condition above covers the piecewise non-negative constant case, but does not allow for $a$ to be negative. If $a<0$ for all $x$, then the above could be rewritten, and a solution would also be guaranteed. The problems arise when $a$ is allowed to switch between positive and negative over $\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you for your time! So, you substituted my problem $-div(a\nabla u)=f$ (the operator is $H^2(\Omega) \rightarrow L^2(\Omega)$) with another (variational) problem, in which we have  the (coercive) bilinear form $a(x,y)=<Ax,y>$ with $A:H_0^1(\Omega) \rightarrow H_0^1(\Omega)$, and the linear form $L(f,y)$ with $f \in H^{-1}(\Omega)$. Now I wonder (i) if we always can move from the first problem to the second and (ii) what implication it has on $a$, because intuitively, the first problem demands more smoothness from $a$ than the second one. Again, I appreciate your time!

Comment: A solution to the strong formulation always implies a solution to the weak formulation. However, the inverse is not always true, as you pointed out. If $u$ solves $\langle a\nabla u,\nabla v\rangle_{\Omega}=\langle f,v\rangle_{\Omega}$ for all $v\in H^1_0(\Omega)$, but does not solve the strong formulation, then we call $u$ a weak solution. Often, especially in FEM, we are happy with a weak solution. However, I am not sure what restrictions we must put on $a$ to enforce a strong solution - it is quite possible we would also require further regularity on $f$.